# MariaDB always show SSL not in use when I start mysqld with --ssl

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb

- CentOS 7.2.1511
- Linux 3.10.0-123.9.3.el7.x86_64
- MariaDB: 10.1.11

/etc/my.cnf

```
#
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]
ssl
ssl-ca       = /root/ca.pem
ssl-cert     = /root/server-cert.pem
ssl-key      = /root/server-key.pem 
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
port         = 3306
max_allowed_packet = 16M


[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 16M
```

I started mariadb with command:

```
systemctl start mysql
```

Then I login mysql with root typed `status` shows SSL `Not in use`. Then I typed

```
show variables like '%ssl%';
```

And I get a table:

```
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| Variable_name       | Value                           |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
| have_openssl        | YES                             |
| have_ssl            | DISABLED                        |
| ssl_ca              | /root/ca.pem                    |
| ssl_capath          |                                 |
| ssl_cert            | /root/server-cert.pem           |
| ssl_cipher          |                                 |
| ssl_crl             |                                 |
| ssl_crlpath         |                                 |
| ssl_key             | /root/server-key.pem            |
| version_ssl_library | OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013 |
+---------------------+---------------------------------+
```

At last I even tried to login with ssl and it failed obviously.

**UPDATE**

Here are some warning messages in the error log file:

```
[Warning] Failed to setup SSL
[Warning] SSL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed
[Warning] SSL error: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied
[Warning] SSL error: error:2006D002:BIO_new_file:system lib
[warning] SSL error: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in you log files. What exactly are you doing and what exactly are the error messages you see?

Comment: @lain Thank you for reminding me of that. I found some SSL error messages in  MariaDB error log file. Maybe it is the key to the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB is not allowed to access files in root's home directory `/root`. Thus, the CA, certificate and private key files are unreadable.

The standard locations for these files on RHEL are in directories under `/etc/pki`: `/etc/pki/CA`, `/etc/pki/tls/certs` and `/etc/pki/tls/private`. If you **copy** them here, and set the proper ownership and permissions so that MariaDB can *read* them, you will find that it works. Alternately, you can place the certificates and private key file in a subdirectory of `/etc/mysql`.

Comment: It worked! I put certs in `/root` directory, that's the problem.